# Getting a git error trying to do "v up" on Linux

Tags: vlang

I downloaded the zip file for Linux and extracted it to /usr/bin/v. It works fine. But when I run "v up" it tells me that:

```
/usr/bin/v> sudo ./v up
Updating V...
From https://github.com/vlang/v
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
[long list of files]
Aborting
```

Is there a git command I can do to get around this?

Comment: https://github.com/vlang/v/issues/18772